# A custom Listener which listen for online event

Tags: android, listener

Basically i want to make a custom listener for my application which listen for availability of new data in server. This listener will periodically check for new available content that could be load in UI same as facebook app that shows new stories are available in news feed. I don't want a full code i just want a basic idea how it can be achieve.

Comment: I guess you can use a service to do that, this service would be running in the background and querying your server at regular intervals. In order to see if there is new content, I guess you'd have two ways, 1st is keeping track on what was previously loaded and see if it differs from the new response, another would be to pass the last update date to your server, and it would return only new content.

Comment: You also can use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Whenever your server have a new update, you can push a message to your device. Then your device can do whatever you want based on the new update and do not need to do the interval loop.

Comment: Joey, can you put your comment as an answer. Joey's answer is good. Use GCM and BroadcastReceivers  to receive updates from your server. Take a look at this link https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check periodically the contents of a web service, I suggest you to:

- write a class that connects to your web service using for example `HttpURLConnection`. This class will handle all exceptions and download a valid XML / JSON.
- write a different class that parses this data and convert into your Model Objects. That is, from a big JSON you'll convert it into Person objects, containing Address objects (that's just an example)
- that way, you can write Unit Tests for the parsing phase and mock the web service to test "the accessing the network" phase
- Once you have this working you need a simple Android Service (extend `android.app.Service` class). You'll start this service when your App starts
- This service will access the network, fetch all data, convert it, pass it to your main App. Once everything is done, put your Service to sleep for a given interval, for example using Thread.sleep() method.
- The Service will be running while some variable `shouldRun` is true. When this variable changes into false, the service will finish
- To stop the Service you can use a notification sent from a menu option. Your service can listen to that notification and then change `shouldRun`accordingly

  **Note:** As Joey Chong suggest in his comment, you have two ways to do this:
- polling your server, that is, sending messages from your app at regular intervals to check for new data (that's what's described before)
- getting a message from some provider when it detects data has changed in your server.

The three first steps are common for both methods.